# Edit an existing WooCommerce meta box in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to edit an existing meta box that is being added by a plugin (WooCommerce) in Wordpress, but I do not know how to do this.

The meta box is added with this line:

```
add_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-data', __('Product Data', 'woocommerce'), 'woocommerce_product_data_box', 'product', 'normal', 'high' );
```

...so the function outputting the HTML to screen is `woocommerce_product_data_box()`. Is there any way to edit this function without loosing it all? I only want to remove parts of it and without editing the original function.

Can I accomplish this with filters somehow? Or any other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the actual function that writes the meta box for that in the `writepanel-product_data.php` file.  At line 24:

```
function woocommerce_product_data_box()
```

That lists everything in the product data.  You can add text boxes or drop downs by using the WooCommerce API.  Find the place you'd like to add, or delete, then-

For a text field -

```
woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 'id' => 'YOURCUSTOMID', 'class' => '', 'label' => __('THELABELOFTHEFIELD', 'woocommerce') ) );
```

For a drop down -

```
woocommerce_wp_select( array( 'id' => 'YOURCUSTOMID', 'label' => __('THELABELOFTHEFIELD', 'woocommerce'), 'options' => array(
            'OPTION1' => __('Option 1', 'woocommerce'),
            'OPTION2' => __('Option 2', 'woocommerce'),
            'OPTION3' => __('Option 3', 'woocommerce'),
            'OPTION4' => __('Option 4', 'woocommerce'),
            'OPTION5' => __('Option 5', 'woocommerce')
            ) ) );
```

So, you give the input an ID, **YOURCUSTOMID**, and then label it whatever you want the admin to see when they are filling out the field, **THELABELOFTHEFIELD**.

The same with custom meta boxes in Wordpress posts/pages, you still have to save it, though.  Find the function `woocommerce_process_product_meta()` somewhere around line 600.  The comments above will tell you it is saving the meta box data.  Then, insert a line of code to save whatever custom ID you just gathered -

```
 update_post_meta( $post_id, 'YOURCUSTOMID', stripslashes( $_POST['YOURCUSTOMID'] ) );
```

and just change it for you custom ID.  Just make sure you put that line of code anywhere after the `global`s are declared.

Naturally, for removing fields, you can just comment out the fields that you don't want gathered in both of those functions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Where can I find `writepanel-product_data.php` I am using v2.3.8